# Sails startDownload not working - TypeError: sails.startDownload is not a function

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am following https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-attachment

My code looks like this:

```
let file = require('path').resolve(document.path)
if (fs.existsSync(file)) {
  this.res.attachment(document.name)
  let downloading = await sails.startDownload(document.fsPath)
  return exits.success(downloading)
}
```

Exits:

```
  exits: {
    success: {
      statusCode: 200,
      description: 'Document has been sent for download.'
    },
  }
```

I am getting error 
`TypeError: sails.startDownload is not a function`

Sails version `1.1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed [sails-hook-uploads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-uploads) as mentioned in the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-attachment#?example) you have linked to?